# memoir: change numwidth in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am trying to change the width of figure numbers in the toc, lof, and lot. This works fine for the toc:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newcommand{\Fig}{\begin{figure}\caption{test}\rule{10pt}{10pt}\end{figure}}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{20mm}
\setlength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{20mm}
\setlength{\cftsectionindent}{0mm}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{One} \Fig
\section{OneOne} \Fig
\section{OneTwo} \Fig
\chapter{Two} \Fig
\section{TwoOne} \Fig
\section{TwoTwo} \Fig
\end{document}
```

But the list of figures is unchanged; how can I change that, too?
Here is my output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{20mm}
\setlength{\cfttablenumwidth}{20mm}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newcommand{\Fig}{\begin{figure}\caption{test}\rule{10pt}{10pt}\end{figure}}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{20mm}
\setlength{\cftsectionnumwidth}{20mm}
\setlength{\cftfigurenumwidth}{20mm}
\setlength{\cfttablenumwidth}{20mm}
\setlength{\cftsectionindent}{0mm}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{One} \Fig
\section{OneOne} \Fig
\section{OneTwo} \Fig
\chapter{Two} \Fig
\section{TwoOne} \Fig
\section{TwoTwo} \Fig
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I have been looking for that for days! But where do I find this? It's not in memoir.cls, nor in memman.pdf.

Comment: @WyboDekker yes, it is. In Table 9.3 (page 162) of `memman` you see the various values for the `K` placeholder in the `\cftX...` family of commands; amongst them you find `figure` and `table`

Comment: Thanks - I missed that one, i.e. I didn't realize that that was what I needed.

Comment: Table 9.3's on p150 now, but also search for [cftKnumwidth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123953/48816).