# Increasing spacing between section number and title in the table of contents

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir

I'm using the simple ordinary `\tableofcontents` command to produce a table of contents, and I find that the resulting spacing between the section number and the section title is too small:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to fix this, please. My documentclass is `memoir`, if that matters.

Comment: similar: [Change Spacing Between Internal TOC numbering and subsection titles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/579); also [How to modify the indentation before sectioning titles in the table of contents?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33841/579)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The width for the section numbers in the ToC is defined by the length called `\cftKnumwidth`, where `K` should be replaced by the sectioning level, i.e. `chapter`, `section`, etc. You can change it with `\setlength`, e.g.

```
\setlength\cftsectionnumwidth{4em}
```

See section **9.2.2 Typesetting the entries** of the `memoir` manual for more on this.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
% \setlength\cftsectionnumwidth{4em} % uncomment to see difference
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\setcounter{section}{999} % just for this example
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Or if you are using the book class, as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336618/50702 and Torbjørn T.'s comment below:

```
\documentclass{book}
% note you need the subfigure option if you are using the subfigure package
%\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength\cftsecnumwidth{4em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\setcounter{section}{999} 
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I got the result I wanted after a lot of iterative fiddling with the length parameter. This is one of those occasions where a visual interface would have been very useful. Or, maybe Latex could be smarter about this: the minimum space would be a much easier parameter to work with, rather than thr indent distance. But, anyway, it works, after some fiddling. Thanks again.

Comment: Could it be that this solution does not work in the book class? I get `! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \cftsectionnumwidth \setlength #1#2->#1 #2\relax l.113 \setlength \cftsectionnumwidth{4em}`

Comment: @Zelphir Yes, that is correct, the `\cft..` macros are not defined in `book`.  The `tocloft` defines similar commands for customizing the ToC though, so try adding `\usepackage{tocloft}`.

Comment: Does not work in report class, even after adding \usepackage{tocloft}.

Comment: @rasha I probably misremembered, as stated in the `tocloft` manual the corresponding length is `\cftsecnumwidth`, i.e. `sec` instead of `section`. Change that, and it works.

Comment: it does not work in article class. What would be the option in this case?

Comment: @PatrickElPollo Did you read the other comments just above yours?

Comment: Oh. sorry. thanks

Answer (score 18):

If you have huge numbers in the ToC, you can use the `\cftsetindents` command (`texdoc memoir`, page 153) in the preamble, to control the space before and after the numbers,   with this syntax:

`\cftsetindents{`***kind***`}{`***indent***`}{`***numwidth***`}`

Where *kind* in the sectioning level (e.g., subsection) *indent* is the length of the indent (space before the numbers) and *numwidth* is the space for the numbers **and** the separation of section titles.

For example:

```
\cftsetindents{section}{1em}{3em}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I had  huge numbers in my toc, will the previous answer (using \cftKnumwidth) not work?  What are the pros and cons of the two solutions?

Comment: @bubba. Torbjørn T. answer works. I made this answer in parallel and I hesitated to left  because this, but I left anyway because for huge numbers and long titles could be interesting a higher `numwith` but also a lower `indent` value (even `0em`) and I think that this solution is  more flexible but not less "user friendly".