# "Command \c@lofdepth already defined" when using packages subfigure and tocloft

Tags: tocloft

I know there are many questions like the title; however, I tried many ways and still cannot fix it.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[tc]{titlepic}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[top=1.25in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{navigator}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}{color}   
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks=true,
   linkcolor=blue,
   filecolor=magenta,      
   urlcolor=cyan,
   allcolors=blue
}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{case}{}{}{}{}{}{:}{ }{}
\theoremstyle{case}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}
%\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}               
  {
      \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
      \newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[theorem]
      \theoremstyle{definition}
      \newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
      \newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
      \newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
  }
\usepackage{framed,color}
%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
%\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
```

However, when I compile it, it shows:

"ommand \c@lofdepth already defined."

How to fix it?

Comment: What is the `subgraph` package? Why do you claim it is the source of the conflict and yet post a very long preamble to an incomplete document (isn't a lot of it unnecessary according to the title of your question)? And why doesn't this very long preamble contain a line like `\usepackage{subgraph}`? Please read about how to construct a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)): it really is called for here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Load the `tocloft` package with the option `subfigure`.

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
```

Moreover, load the package `hyperref` last. (This is not related to your current problem, but may give rise to further ones.)