# Using \numwidth in KOMA class for list of figures and list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Hi I want to increase the spacing for my numbers in my List of Figures and List of Tables in my KOMA class document. Basically I need what was done here:[memoir: change numwidth in list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73032/memoir-change-numwidth-in-list-of-figures)

for the KOMA Class. I know that there is `\DeclareTOCEntryStyle` 
but I can't figure out how to use it. I would need a numwidth of 3em for both lists.

I am not using any other style for both lists, I just need to change the numwidth.

Comment: Please -- as usual -- add an compilable code ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a KOMA-Script class you can use

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3em]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3em]{tocline}{table}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3em]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=3em]{tocline}{table}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{A chapter}
\captionof{table}{A table caption}
\captionof{table}{A second table caption}
\captionof{figure}{A figure caption}
\chapter{A second chapter}
\captionof{table}{A table caption}
\captionof{table}{A second table caption}
\captionof{figure}{A figure caption}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I had to make sure not to use option listof=flat in the KOMA class options, otherwise it will override the TOCStyle.